# Программа Sigil. HTML&CSS

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

В программировании не разбираюсь, я любитель, пытаюсь вставить код из ChatGPT и не всегда получается, чтобы он работал

В общем, застрял, проблема такая:

Создал примечания для книги, чтобы делать сноски, начал с первой сноски, заякорил нужный мне текст и добавил ID — note001, чтобы сослаться на него:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, перешёл к тексту, создал сноску "1"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал ссылку на note001, сноска заработала, но на телефоне сноска не отображалась, я по примеру какой-то книги добавил теги sup, поставил их до и после "1"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сноска стала отображаться, но она занимает половину страницы, а мне надо, чтобы она переходила либо на другую страницу, либо заканчивалась многоточием, чтобы не был весь текст, как это сделать?

Скрин того, как отображаются сноски:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]